# Restricting input to textbox: allowing only numbers and decimal point

Tags: javascript, html

How can I restrict input to a text-box so that it accepts only numbers and the decimal point?

Comment: I know you specify a text box but why not use a type="number"? That solves most of the problem for you. Then use some css to hide the up/down spinners. Additionally, some Jquery that stops cut and paste. I'd provide an answer but there are already 30 and I'd prob get voted down for not specifically answering the question. Sometimes, I feel that the answer lies in a different approach.

Answer (score 172, accepted):

```html
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <SCRIPT language=Javascript>
       <!--
       function isNumberKey(evt)
       {
          var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
          if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 
            && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
             return false;

          return true;
       }
       //-->
    </SCRIPT>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <INPUT id="txtChar" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" 
           type="text" name="txtChar">
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

This really works!

Comment: Why is && charCode >31 needed?

Comment: Character 31 is the Unit Separator Code. Pretty much numbers and text are between 32 and higher. The code reads that should the character code entered is not the decimal AND is higher than 31 (Unit separator) but lower than 48 (number zero) or higher than 57 (number nine), don't accept it.

Comment: please add a reference to source : http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/39/how-can-i-use-javascript-to-allow-only-numbers-to-be-entered-in-a-textbox

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10023845/regex-in-javascript-for-validating-decimal-number

Comment: if (charCode == 46 && evt.srcElement.value.split('.').length>1) {
            return false;
        }

It will privent multiple '.'... :)

Comment: include keypad numkeys and periods with: `&& charCode != 190 && charCode != 110 && (charCode > 105 || charCode < 96)`

Comment: Back space is not working, It allows more than 2 characters after decimal place.

Comment: it does not work when user paste string directly to the textbox

Comment: how to disable decimal dot also ?

Comment: include "-" negative number "&& charCode != 45"

Comment: This fails on copy'n'paste, drag'n'drop and it disabled some important keyboard functionality like the arrow keys or `ctrl+a` for example. Take a look at my answer below for a solution that works with all that.

Comment: it is accepting more than one '. [ period ]', which is wrong i guess.

Comment: i can paste non numeric chars in this field, is there any workaround for this/

Comment: Working for 435.23.23.232.....1616....but it should not take

Comment: I use this solution on "event listener" separate js file, but it didn't work. Anyone have idea? [link](https://jsfiddle.net/0usk37oq/)

Answer (score 40):

The accepted solution is not complete, since you can enter multiple '.', for example 24....22..22. with some small modifications it will work as intended:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function isNumberKey(txt, evt) {
      var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
      if (charCode == 46) {
        //Check if the text already contains the . character
        if (txt.value.indexOf('.') === -1) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      } else {
        if (charCode > 31 &&
          (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
          return false;
      }
      return true;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(this, event);" />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I used your answer but I modified this onkeypress="return isNumberKey(this,event);"

Comment: yes I think it is optional to type pass the event, since it works with both cases, thanks

Comment: saved us a few key strokes..  tq

Comment: only problem with this one is you can copy paste in text. Adding to input element `ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" oncontextmenu="return false;"` seems to be enough

Comment: It's a mis-service to every user to prevent them from using drag-and-drop or copy-and-paste.

Answer (score 30):

```
form.onsubmit = function(){
    return textarea.value.match(/^\d+(\.\d+)?$/);
}
```

Is this what you're looking for?

I hope it helps.

EDIT: I edited my example above so that there can only be one period, preceded by at least one digit and followed by at least one digit.

Comment: Think this will also validate '99.23.65.86' ....
But i guess the question was about validating '56987.32' with single dot.....

Comment: i see the poster has since edited his/her original question. thanks for the update!

Comment: I'd better use  /^\d+([\.,]\d+)?$/  to support international numbers ( where comma is used instead of dot )

Answer (score 23):

Here is one more solution which allows for decimal numbers and also limits the digits after decimal to 2 decimal places.

```js
function isNumberKey(evt, element) {
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
  if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) && !(charCode == 46 || charCode == 8))
    return false;
  else {
    var len = $(element).val().length;
    var index = $(element).val().indexOf('.');
    if (index > 0 && charCode == 46) {
      return false;
    }
    if (index > 0) {
      var CharAfterdot = (len + 1) - index;
      if (CharAfterdot > 3) {
        return false;
      }
    }

  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="rate" placeholder="Billing Rate" required onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event,this)">
```

Comment: Almost perfect.. the last condition of your `if` is missing a capitalised "C".

Comment: Beautiful solution!!

Comment: Beutiful. Works perfectly for me.

Comment: Note that this solution allows multiple dots (`.`), dash (`-`) and the letter `e` when text is pasted or dropped onto the field. The HTML element will also show two arrows for incrementing and decrementing the number by default in Chrome. The decrementing button allows the number to fall below zero.

Comment: This solution doesn't allow enter anything on the left if you already placed 2 decimal points, also you will have to handle paste.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks Mate. :)

Answer (score 18):

All solutions presented here are using single key events. This is very error prone since input can be also given using copy'n'paste or drag'n'drop. Also some of the solutions restrict the usage of non-character keys like `ctrl+c`, `Pos1` etc.

I suggest rather than checking every key press you check whether the result is valid in respect to your expectations.

```js
var validNumber = new RegExp(/^\d*\.?\d*$/);
var lastValid = document.getElementById("test1").value;
function validateNumber(elem) {
  if (validNumber.test(elem.value)) {
    lastValid = elem.value;
  } else {
    elem.value = lastValid;
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea id="test1" oninput="validateNumber(this);" ></textarea>
```

The `oninput` event is triggered just after something was changed in the text area and before being rendered.

You can extend the RegEx to whatever number format you want to accept. This is far more maintainable and extendible than checking for single key presses.

Comment: This is the most elegant solution!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. We can improve the regex to `new RegExp(/^\d*\.?\d{0,2}$/);` to limit the decimals places to 2.

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
   <HTML>
   <HEAD>
   <SCRIPT language=Javascript>
      <!--
      function isNumberKey(evt)
      {
         var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
         if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
            return false;

         return true;
      }
      //-->
   </SCRIPT>
   </HEAD>
   <BODY>
      <INPUT id="txtChar" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" type="text" name="txtChar">
   </BODY>
  </HTML>
```

Answer (score 4):

Just need to apply this method in Jquery and you can validate your textbox to just accept number with a decimal only.

```
function IsFloatOnly(element) {    
var value = $(element).val(); 
var regExp ="^\\d+(\\.\\d+)?$";
return value.match(regExp); 
}
```

Please see working demo [here](http://jsbin.com/ImIruPEf/3/edit)

Answer (score 3):

```js
function onlyDotsAndNumbers(txt, event) {
        var charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode
        if (charCode == 46) {
            if (txt.value.indexOf(".") < 0)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        if (txt.value.indexOf(".") > 0) {
            var txtlen = txt.value.length;
            var dotpos = txt.value.indexOf(".");
            //Change the number here to allow more decimal points than 2
            if ((txtlen - dotpos) > 2)
                return false;
        }

        if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
            return false;

        return true;
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtAmount" onkeypress="return onlyDotsAndNumbers(this,event);" maxlength="12" oncopy="return false" ondrag="return false" ondrop="return false" onpaste="return false" />
```

Only Numbers, One decimal point, Two decimal places, No Copy Paste.

Comment: how to use comma instead of dot as decimal seperator for this solution?

Answer (score 2):

here is script that cas help you :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// price text-box allow numeric and allow 2 decimal points only
function extractNumber(obj, decimalPlaces, allowNegative)
{
    var temp = obj.value;

    // avoid changing things if already formatted correctly
    var reg0Str = '[0-9]*';
    if (decimalPlaces > 0) {
        reg0Str += '\[\,\.]?[0-9]{0,' + decimalPlaces + '}';
    } else if (decimalPlaces < 0) {
        reg0Str += '\[\,\.]?[0-9]*';
    }
    reg0Str = allowNegative ? '^-?' + reg0Str : '^' + reg0Str;
    reg0Str = reg0Str + '$';
    var reg0 = new RegExp(reg0Str);
    if (reg0.test(temp)) return true;

    // first replace all non numbers
    var reg1Str = '[^0-9' + (decimalPlaces != 0 ? '.' : '') + (decimalPlaces != 0 ? ',' : '') + (allowNegative ? '-' : '') + ']';
    var reg1 = new RegExp(reg1Str, 'g');
    temp = temp.replace(reg1, '');

    if (allowNegative) {
        // replace extra negative
        var hasNegative = temp.length > 0 && temp.charAt(0) == '-';
        var reg2 = /-/g;
        temp = temp.replace(reg2, '');
        if (hasNegative) temp = '-' + temp;
    }

    if (decimalPlaces != 0) {
        var reg3 = /[\,\.]/g;
        var reg3Array = reg3.exec(temp);
        if (reg3Array != null) {
            // keep only first occurrence of .
            //  and the number of places specified by decimalPlaces or the entire string if decimalPlaces < 0
            var reg3Right = temp.substring(reg3Array.index + reg3Array[0].length);
            reg3Right = reg3Right.replace(reg3, '');
            reg3Right = decimalPlaces > 0 ? reg3Right.substring(0, decimalPlaces) : reg3Right;
            temp = temp.substring(0,reg3Array.index) + '.' + reg3Right;
        }
    }

    obj.value = temp;
}
function blockNonNumbers(obj, e, allowDecimal, allowNegative)
{
    var key;
    var isCtrl = false;
    var keychar;
    var reg;
    if(window.event) {
        key = e.keyCode;
        isCtrl = window.event.ctrlKey
    }
    else if(e.which) {
        key = e.which;
        isCtrl = e.ctrlKey;
    }

    if (isNaN(key)) return true;

    keychar = String.fromCharCode(key);

    // check for backspace or delete, or if Ctrl was pressed
    if (key == 8 || isCtrl)
    {
        return true;
    }

    reg = /\d/;
    var isFirstN = allowNegative ? keychar == '-' && obj.value.indexOf('-') == -1 : false;
    var isFirstD = allowDecimal ? keychar == '.' && obj.value.indexOf('.') == -1 : false;
    var isFirstC = allowDecimal ? keychar == ',' && obj.value.indexOf(',') == -1 : false;
    return isFirstN || isFirstD || isFirstC || reg.test(keychar);
}
function blockInvalid(obj)
{
    var temp=obj.value;
    if(temp=="-")
    {
        temp="";
    }

    if (temp.indexOf(".")==temp.length-1 && temp.indexOf(".")!=-1)
    {
        temp=temp+"00";
    }
    if (temp.indexOf(".")==0)
    {
        temp="0"+temp;
    }
    if (temp.indexOf(".")==1 && temp.indexOf("-")==0)
    {
        temp=temp.replace("-","-0") ;
    }
    if (temp.indexOf(",")==temp.length-1 && temp.indexOf(",")!=-1)
    {
        temp=temp+"00";
    }
    if (temp.indexOf(",")==0)
    {
        temp="0"+temp;
    }
    if (temp.indexOf(",")==1 && temp.indexOf("-")==0)
    {
        temp=temp.replace("-","-0") ;
    }
    temp=temp.replace(",",".") ;
    obj.value=temp;
}
// end of price text-box allow numeric and allow 2 decimal points only
</script>

<input type="Text" id="id" value="" onblur="extractNumber(this,2,true);blockInvalid(this);" onkeyup="extractNumber(this,2,true);" onkeypress="return blockNonNumbers(this, event, true, true);">
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone stumbling here like I did, here is a jQuery 1.10.2 version I wrote which is working very well for me albeit resource intensive:

```
/***************************************************
* Only allow numbers and one decimal in text boxes
***************************************************/
$('body').on('keydown keyup keypress change blur focus paste', 'input[type="text"]', function(){
    var target = $(this);

    var prev_val = target.val();

    setTimeout(function(){
        var chars = target.val().split("");

        var decimal_exist = false;
        var remove_char = false;

        $.each(chars, function(key, value){
            switch(value){
                case '0':
                case '1':
                case '2':
                case '3':
                case '4':
                case '5':
                case '6':
                case '7':
                case '8':
                case '9':
                case '.':
                    if(value === '.'){
                        if(decimal_exist === false){
                            decimal_exist = true;
                        }
                        else{
                            remove_char = true;
                            chars[''+key+''] = '';
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    remove_char = true;
                    chars[''+key+''] = '';
                    break;
            }
        });

        if(prev_val != target.val() && remove_char === true){
            target.val(chars.join(''))
        }
    }, 0);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

A small correction to @rebisco's brilliant answer to validate the decimal perfectly.

```
function isNumberKey(evt) {
    debugger;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
    if (charCode == 46 && evt.srcElement.value.split('.').length>1) {
        return false;
    }
    if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: this is very good. However, I would like to limit it to 2 decimal point, anyway to do that ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want it for float values,

Here is the function I am using

```html
<HTML>

<HEAD>
  <SCRIPT language=Javascript>
    <!--
    function check(e, value) {
      //Check Charater
      var unicode = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
      if (value.indexOf(".") != -1)
        if (unicode == 46) return false;
      if (unicode != 8)
        if ((unicode < 48 || unicode > 57) && unicode != 46) return false;
    }
    //-->
  </SCRIPT>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
  <INPUT id="txtChar" onkeypress="return check(event,value)" type="text" name="txtChar">
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
inputelement.onchange= inputelement.onkeyup= function isnumber(e){
    e= window.event? e.srcElement: e.target;
    while(e.value && parseFloat(e.value)+''!= e.value){
            e.value= e.value.slice(0, -1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function integerwithdot(s, iid){
        var i;
        s = s.toString();
        for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++){
            var c;
            if (s.charAt(i) == ".") {
            } else {
                c = s.charAt(i);
            }
            if (isNaN(c)) {
                c = "";
                for(i=0;i<s.length-1;i++){
                    c += s.charAt(i);
                }
                document.getElementById(iid).value = c;
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your textbox field name is `Income`
Call this validate method when you need to validate your field:

```
function validate() {
    var currency = document.getElementById("Income").value;
      var pattern = /^[1-9]\d*(?:\.\d{0,2})?$/ ;
    if (pattern.test(currency)) {
        alert("Currency is in valid format");
        return true;
    } 
        alert("Currency is not in valid format!Enter in 00.00 format");
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Extending the @rebisco's answer. this below code will allow only numbers and single '.'(period) in the text box.

```
function isNumberKey(evt) {
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
        if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            // If the number field already has . then don't allow to enter . again.
            if (evt.target.value.search(/\./) > -1 && charCode == 46) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Better solution

```
var checkfloats = function(event){
    var charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
    if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;

    if(event.target.value.indexOf('.') >=0 && charCode == 46)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

alternative way to restrict input to a text-box so that it accepts only numbers and the decimal point is to 
use javascript inside the html input. This works for me:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="price" name="price" placeholder="Price" 
vrequired onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1')">
```

--Accepts--

9

9.99

--Do not accept--

9.99.99

ABC

Answer (score 1):

I chose to tackle this on the `oninput` event in order to handle the issue for keyboard pasting, mouse pasting and key strokes. Pass true or false to indicate decimal or integer validation.

It's basically three steps in three one liners. If you don't want to truncate the decimals comment the third step. Adjustments for rounding can be made in the third step as well.

```
// Example Decimal usage;
// <input type="text"  oninput="ValidateNumber(this, true);" />
// Example Integer usage:
// <input type="text"  oninput="ValidateNumber(this, false);" />
function ValidateNumber(elm, isDecimal) {
    try {

        // For integers, replace everything except for numbers with blanks.
        if (!isDecimal) 
            elm.value = elm.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''); 
        else {
            // 1. For decimals, replace everything except for numbers and periods with blanks.
            // 2. Then we'll remove all leading ocurrences (duplicate) periods
            // 3. Then we'll chop off anything after two decimal places.

            // 1. replace everything except for numbers and periods with blanks.
            elm.value = elm.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');

            //2. remove all leading ocurrences (duplicate) periods
            elm.value = elm.value.replace(/\.(?=.*\.)/g, '');

            // 3. chop off anything after two decimal places.
            // In comparison to lengh, our index is behind one count, then we add two for our decimal places.
            var decimalIndex = elm.value.indexOf('.');
            if (decimalIndex != -1) { elm.value = elm.value.substr(0, decimalIndex + 3); }
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
        alert("ValidateNumber " + err);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function isNumberKey(evt)
{
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;

    if(charCode==8 || charCode==13|| charCode==99|| charCode==118 || charCode==46)
    {    
        return true;  
    }

    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
    {   
        return false; 
    }
    return true;
}
```

It will allow only numeric and will let you put "." for decimal.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function isNumberKey(evt) {
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
        if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
            return false;

        return true;
    }

</script>
```

---

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Orderids, new { id = "Orderids", Onkeypress=isNumberKey(event)})
```

This works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from @rebisco answer :

```
function count_appearance(mainStr, searchFor) {
    return (mainStr.split(searchFor).length - 1);
}
function isNumberKey(evt)
{
    $return = true;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
    if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31
            && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        $return = false;
    $val = $(evt.originalTarget).val();
    if (charCode == 46) {
        if (count_appearance($val, '.') > 0) {
            $return = false;
        }
        if ($val.length == 0) {
            $return = false;
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Allows only this format : 123123123[.121213]

Demo here [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UUu3d/)

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will work for you.

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="return chkNumeric(event)" />

<script>
    function chkNumeric(evt) {
        evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
        if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
            if (charCode == 46) { return true; }
            else { return false; }
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code worked for me

The input box with "onkeypress" event as follows

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(this,event);" />
```

The function "isNumberKey" is as follows

```js
function isNumberKey(txt, evt) {
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
  if (charCode == 46) {
    //Check if the text already contains the . character
    if (txt.value.indexOf('.') === -1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
  } else {
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I observed that for all the answers provided here, the things are not working if we select some portion of the text in textbox and try to overwrite that part.
So I modified the function which is as below:

```
    <HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <SCRIPT language=Javascript>
       <!--
       function isNumberKey(evt)
       {
         var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;

if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
{
        return false;
}
 if (charCode == 46 && evt.srcElement.value.split('.').length>1 )
    {

        return false;

    } 

 if(evt.srcElement.selectionStart<evt.srcElement.selectionEnd)
    {
          return true;
    }

  if(evt.srcElement.value.split('.').length>1 && evt.srcElement.value.split('.')[1].length==2)
  {

     return false;
  }


    return true;
       }


       //-->
    </SCRIPT>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <INPUT id="txtChar" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" 
           type="text" name="txtChar">
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

For Decimal numbers and also allowing Negatives numbers with 2 places for decimals after the point... I modified the function to:

```
<input type="text" id="txtSample" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event,this)"/>



function isNumberKey(evt, element){

        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
        if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) && !(charCode == 46 || charCode == 8 || charCode == 45))
            return false;
        else {
            var len = $(element).val().length;

            // Validation Point
            var index = $(element).val().indexOf('.');
            if ((index > 0 && charCode == 46) || len == 0 && charCode == 46) {
                return false;
            }
            if (index > 0) {
                var CharAfterdot = (len + 1) - index;
                if (CharAfterdot > 3) {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            // Validating Negative sign
            index = $(element).val().indexOf('-');
            if ((index > 0 && charCode == 45) || (len > 0 && charCode == 45)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" class="number_only" />    
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.number_only').keypress(function (event) {
        return isNumber(event, this)
    });        
});

function isNumber(evt, element) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode

    if ((charCode != 45 || $(element).val().indexOf('-') != -1) && (charCode != 46 || $(element).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && ((charCode < 48 && charCode != 8) || charCode > 57)){
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
} 
</script>
```

http://www.encodedna.com/2013/05/enter-only-numbers-using-jquery.htm

Answer (score 0):

Best and working solution with Pure-Javascript sample
Live demo : https://jsfiddle.net/manoj2010/ygkpa89o/

```html
<script>
function removeCommas(nStr) {
    if (nStr == null || nStr == "")
        return ""; 
    return nStr.toString().replace(/,/g, "");
}

function NumbersOnly(myfield, e, dec,neg)
{        
    if (isNaN(removeCommas(myfield.value)) && myfield.value != "-") {
        return false;
    }
    var allowNegativeNumber = neg || false;
    var key;
    var keychar;

    if (window.event)
        key = window.event.keyCode;
    else if (e)
        key = e.which;
    else
        return true;
    keychar = String.fromCharCode(key);
    var srcEl = e.srcElement ? e.srcElement : e.target;    
    // control keys
    if ((key == null) || (key == 0) || (key == 8) ||
                (key == 9) || (key == 13) || (key == 27))
        return true;

    // numbers
    else if ((("0123456789").indexOf(keychar) > -1))
        return true;

    // decimal point jump
    else if (dec && (keychar == ".")) {
        //myfield.form.elements[dec].focus();
        return srcEl.value.indexOf(".") == -1;        
    }

    //allow negative numbers
    else if (allowNegativeNumber && (keychar == "-")) {    
        return (srcEl.value.length == 0 || srcEl.value == "0.00")
    }
    else
        return false;
}
</script>
<input name="txtDiscountSum" type="text" onKeyPress="return NumbersOnly(this, event,true)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Working on the issue myself, and that's what I've got so far. This more or less works, but it's impossible to add minus afterwards due to the new value check. Also doesn't allow comma as a thousand separator, only decimal.

It's not perfect, but might give some ideas.

```
app.directive('isNumber', function () {
            return function (scope, elem, attrs) {
                elem.bind('keypress', function (evt) {
                    var keyCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
                    var testValue = (elem[0].value + String.fromCharCode(keyCode) + "0").replace(/ /g, ""); //check ignores spaces
                    var regex = /^\-?\d+((\.|\,)\d+)?$/;                        
                    var allowedChars = [8,9,13,27,32,37,39,44,45, 46] //control keys and separators             

                   //allows numbers, separators and controll keys and rejects others
                    if ((keyCode > 47 && keyCode < 58) || allowedChars.indexOf(keyCode) >= 0) {             
                        //test the string with regex, decline if doesn't fit
                        if (elem[0].value != "" && !regex.test(testValue)) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            return false;
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                    event.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                });
            };
        });
```

Allows:

11 11 .245 (in controller formatted on blur to 1111.245)

11,44

-123.123

-1 014

0123 (formatted on blur to 123)

doesn't allow:

!@#$/*

abc

11.11.1

11,11.1

.42

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event,this)">

<script>
   function isNumberKey(evt, obj) {

            var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
            var value = obj.value;
            var dotcontains = value.indexOf(".") != -1;
            if (dotcontains)
                if (charCode == 46) return false;
            if (charCode == 46) return true;
            if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
                return false;
            return true;
        }


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is very old but still we often get such requirements. There are many examples however many seems to be too **verbose** or **complex** for a simple implimentation.

See this https://jsfiddle.net/vibs2006/rn0fvxuk/ and improve it (if you can). It works on IE, Firefox, Chrome and Edge Browser.

Here is the working code.

```js
        
        function IsNumeric(e) {
        var IsValidationSuccessful = false;
        console.log(e.target.value);
        document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = "You just typed ''" + e.key + "''";
        //console.log("e.Key Value = "+e.key);
        switch (e.key)
         {         
             case "1":
             case "2":
             case "3":
             case "4":
             case "5":
             case "6":
             case "7":
             case "8":
             case "9":
             case "0":
             case "Backspace":             
                 IsValidationSuccessful = true;
                 break;
                 
       case "Decimal":  //Numpad Decimal in Edge Browser
             case ".":        //Numpad Decimal in Chrome and Firefox                      
             case "Del":    // Internet Explorer 11 and less Numpad Decimal 
                 if (e.target.value.indexOf(".") >= 1) //Checking if already Decimal exists
                 {
                     IsValidationSuccessful = false;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     IsValidationSuccessful = true;
                 }
                 break;

             default:
                 IsValidationSuccessful = false;
         }
         //debugger;
         if(IsValidationSuccessful == false){
         
         document.getElementById("error").style = "display:Block";
         }else{
         document.getElementById("error").style = "display:none";
         }
         
         return IsValidationSuccessful;
        }
```

```html
Numeric Value: <input type="number" id="text1" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" /><br />
    <span id="error" style="color: Red; display: none">* Input digits (0 - 9) and Decimals Only</span><br />
    <div id="info"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'>
```

You can restrict values to be entered by user by specifying ASCII value range.
**Example** : 48 to 57 for numeric values (0 to 9)

Answer (score -1):

```
document.getElementById('value').addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    var key   = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;

/*lenght of value to use with index to know how many numbers after.*/

    var len = $('#value').val().length;
    var index = $('#value').val().indexOf('.');
    if (!( [8, 9, 13, 27, 46, 110, 190].indexOf(key) !== -1 ||
                    (key == 65 && ( e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey  ) ) ||
                    (key >= 35 && key <= 40) ||
                    (key >= 48 && key <= 57 && !(e.shiftKey || e.altKey)) ||
                    (key >= 96 && key <= 105)
            )){
        e.preventDefault();
    }

/*if theres a . count how many and if reachs 2 digits after . it blocks*/ 

    if (index > 0) {
        var CharAfterdot = (len + 1) - index;
        if (CharAfterdot > 3) {

/*permits the backsapce to remove :D could be improved*/

            if (!(key == 8))
            {
                e.preventDefault();
            }

/*blocks if you try to add a new . */

        }else if ( key == 110) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }

/*if you try to add a . and theres no digit yet it adds a 0.*/

    } else if( key == 110&& len==0){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#value').val('0.');
    }
});
```

Comment: permits 2 decimals and if you add a . it adds 0. and limits to 1 . and 2 decimal

Comment: Some explanation for the code would be useful. Also, your comment under the answer should instead be included as part of the answer as additional explanation.