# Check with Javascript if a textarea value is numeric

Tags: javascript, html, forms, textarea

I have in my webpage a form called 'contact_form' and I have in it a textarea where I want to allow to type only numbers inside. How do I check it in submission with Javascript?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have your tried so far? Could you post your code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Restricting input to textbox: allowing only numbers and decimal point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808184/restricting-input-to-textbox-allowing-only-numbers-and-decimal-point)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML:**

`<textarea id="text"></textarea>​`

**JavaScript:**

```
var re=/\d/,
    allowedCodes = [37, 39, 8, 9], // left and right arrows, backspace and tab
    text = document.getElementById('text');

text.onkeydown = function(e) {
    var code;
    if(window.event) { // IE8 and earlier
        code = e.keyCode;
    } else if(e.which) { // IE9/Firefox/Chrome/Opera/Safari
        code = e.which;
    }
    if(allowedCodes.indexOf(code) > -1) {
        return true;
    }
    return !e.shiftKey && re.test(String.fromCharCode(code));
};​
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/KuZEB/)**