# Restriction in typing textbox in html using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i would like to seek some help....my problem is my script restricts everything but numbers...i want to do is...i can type double numbers...like 1.232....i dont want to restrict the point`(.)`...can anyone help me do that?

current code:

```
<input autocomplete="off" class="search_form_input" name="optA1" id="optA1" onkeypress="return isnumeric(event)" type="text" onchange="optTotal1()" />
```

script code:

```
<script type="application/javascript">

  function isnumeric(evt)
      {
         var CharacterCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode

         if (CharacterCode > 31 && (CharacterCode < 48 || CharacterCode > 57))
            return false;

         return true;
      }

</script>
```

Comment: add `alert(CharacterCode);` after you define it, refresh your page, type a `.` in the input, record the number, add `&& CharacterCode != X` to your if statement where X is your recorded number, remove your `alert`.

Comment: Not sure, but your code allows me to type more than just digits.

Comment: maybe look at some suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808184/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
$('input').on('keydown', function(e) {
    var dot = $(this).val().indexOf('.');
    if((e.which >= 48 && e.which <= 57) ||
       (e.which >= 96 && e.which <= 105) ||
        ((e.which == 190 || e.which == 110) && dot == -1)
        ) return true;
    return false;
});
```

This will also check your numpad and if you already have a `.` in your value.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5qzJ2/)

Answer (score -1):

I'd consider a regexp:

`var x=document.getElementById("optA1").value;
return /[\d\.]+/.test(x);`

Or you could pass the value through the function and use it that way.

Comment: This is not going to work, the `CharacterCode` will always pass because it is a digit.

Comment: Oops i was thinking that CharacterCode was the the actual character! Ill update!