# How can I make to accept only numbers in input?

Tags: javascript

How can I make to accept only numbers inputs in my code: `-->>` [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/fxvfJ/7/)    ?

Thank you !

Comment: `<input type="number" />`?

Comment: I don't want to make it like that, without up/down arrows

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808184/restricting-input-to-textbox-allowing-only-numbers-and-decimal-point

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to adapt it to my code...

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
<input type="number">
```

or this:

```
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]+">
```

These will only work in HTML5 compatible browsers.

In javascript you can do this:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8j6Ts/2/)

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="test" name="test"/>
```

CSS:

```
var input = document.getElementById("test");

input.oninput = function(e){
    if (/\D/g.test(this.value))
    {
        // Filter non-digits from input value.
        this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work on my code, it still accepts caracters...