# How is HTML restricting text input based on the return value of a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm reading over answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808184/restricting-input-to-textbox-allowing-only-numbers-and-decimal-point), and they all seem to follow a similar theme that I can't understand, and I don't know what I'm looking at enough to try and google it.

They all have this pattern of `onkeypress` return `somefunction`, and `somefunction` often returns a boolean.

I don't understand which part of this is doing the actual restriction.  The return value?  The web browser?  The HTML?

**And how?**

None of this makes any sense.  I'm floundering quite a bit here with my understanding of javascript.  I can't get a handle on what is doing what.  Why does returning `false` or `true` do anything at all?

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I'd very much appreciate it.  A lot of resources I've found are either what an array is and how to declare variables, or they skip straight to a solution.  I'm just trying to figure out what is happening in those solutions.

Here is the pattern:

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="return somefunction()">

<script>
  function somefunction() 
  {
    return false;
  }
</script>

<input type="text" onkeypress="return somefunction2()">
```

and the js

```
function somefunction2()
{
    return false;
}
```

Secondary, why does this work in jsfiddle when it's in a script tag, but not with an attached jsfile?

Comment: Returning false from onkeypress essentially blocks input because it cancels the event. This is HTML behavior. Why it works inline but not in a referenced file, I can't say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript event handlers fire before the default browser behavior is performed.  Returning `false` inside of an event handler prevents the default behavior from occurring.  It also stops the event from bubbling up the event chain to ancestor elements.  In your example, pressing a key while the text input has focus will prevent that key's character from appending to the input value.

Here's some further reading:  [What's the difference between event.stopPropagation and event.preventDefault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963669/whats-the-difference-between-event-stoppropagation-and-event-preventdefault)

Comment: I'm interpreting from your answer that in a text-thing, the "default browser behavior" is to allow the keyboard input, while focus is on text-thing, to render in the text-thing.  Is that far-off?  Is that the default behavior being prevented?  Also, does default browser behavior work in a functionally similar way to addEventListener()?  Thank you.

Comment: Absolutely.  If you've clicked or tabbed into a text input and you begin to type, the expected behavior would be for those keystrokes to display inside the field.  It's the default browser behavior when you press a key.  

Pressing a key also fires a JavaScript `keypress` event. In fact a `keydown` event is fired, followed by `keypress` while a key is held down, and finally a `keyup` event when released.  

If a `keypress` event listener is added to the text input, then a function that you specify will be executed every time that input has focus and a key is pressed.