# How to prevent non numeric Character and accepts 3 decimal places

Tags: javascript

I have this code it's working but it's accept small letter (e) and big (E) 
How can I prevent that? I've seen some similar codes that also accepts (e & E)

```
function isNumberKeyDecimal(evt) 
    {
         var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode

         if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) && charCode != 46)
         return false; 

     return true;
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to accept the simple letter or the capital?

Comment: What exactly you need?

Comment: Is there any reason not to use an `<input type='number'` element?

Comment: Consider using the `pattern` attribute on your input element.

Comment: I need an input like 25.986 , 24, 25.2 , 677 whole number or with decimal places,

Comment: <input type="number" id="numeric" class="numeric" onkeypress="isNumberKeyForDecimal();" pattern="/^[0-9]\.[0-9]{1,3}$/"/>

Comment: checkout the solutions in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808184/restricting-input-to-textbox-allowing-only-numbers-and-decimal-point

Comment: @ Owuor , Thanks a lot, it works, thats it!