# How to allow user to input numbers (+/-) and 1 decimal in JSF <h:inputText onkeypress="">

Tags: html, validation, jsf

I have an `<h:inputText>` tag, and I only want to allow numbers to be entered with no more than 1 decimal.

This allows only numbers, but I cannot get it to allow only 1 decimal.

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.someNumber}"
  size="6" styleClass="some-style"
  onkeypress="if(event.which &lt; 48 || event.which &gt; 57) return false;"
  pt:placeholder="0.0">
</h:inputText>
```

I tried adding `(event.which == 190)` to the `onkeypress` attribute, but I can't get it to work.  (190 is the `.` key)

**Note:** This is trying to restrict what the user can enter into the input field, not validating server side, that already works.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

**Update**
I tried to change the `onkeypress` with `pt:oninput` like the code below. It only allows digits and 1 decimal place, but it does not allow a `-` sign as the first character for negative numbers.

`pt:oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restricting input to textbox: allowing only numbers and decimal point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808184/restricting-input-to-textbox-allowing-only-numbers-and-decimal-point)

Comment: Bewhare that you should bind the inout value to a decimal typed bean property and/or you should add a validator in order to securely restrict input server side.

Comment: Ever thought of using a `mask` look at [this](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/inputMask.xhtml). I hope it helps you

Comment: @fuggerjaki61 that helps a lot. Much better solution.